# C++, VS 2015, fatal error: duplicate resource. type:MANIFEST, name:1, language:0x0409

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, manifest

Everywhere I searched there is only one solution - to set "Embed manifest" as NO in the properties of the project. 
But I need the manifest for setting my project run under admin privileges (otherwise I can't create raw socket properly).
So the question is how this problem can be solved without excluding manifest.. 
There is a manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
<assemblyIdentity 
    version="1.0.0.0" 
    processorArchitecture="X86" 
    name="Microsoft.Windows.Sniffer"
    type="win32" 
/> 
<description>Your app description here</description> 
<dependency> 
    <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity 
            type="win32" 
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
            version="6.0.0.0" 
            processorArchitecture="X86" 
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
            language="*" 
        /> 
    </dependentAssembly> 
</dependency> 
</assembly>
```

And here is "Resource.h"

```
#define IDR_MANIFEST                    1
#define IDM_ABOUTBOX                    0x0010
#define IDI_COMP2COMP                   16
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    100
#define IDS_ABOUTBOX                    101
#define IDD_SNIFFER_DIALOG              102
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDI_IPHeader                    130
#define IDI_ICON2                       131
#define IDI_TCPHEADER                   131
#define IDC_FRM_INTERFACES              1000
#define IDC_CMB_INTERFACES              1001
#define IDC_STARTSNIFFING               1004
#define IDC_TV_PACKETS                  1005

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        132
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1006
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Look in your .rc file for multiple MANIFEST sections.

Comment: you can set "Embed manifest" as NO and manually add to .rc file your file manifest - `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "<path to manifest file>"`

Answer (score 2):

fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:MANIFEST, name:1, language:0x0409

If you encountered this type of error while convert / upgrade legacy VC++ project code to latest framework VS 2012/15/17, then remove the manifest file from resource folder and remove the reference of manifest file from the resource (.rc) file.

Clean the solution & build it again..

Comment: I wasn't sure what a manifest file was, but I guessed it was the `progname.exe.manifest` file in the res directory. I deleted it, and commented out (using \\\) the line containing a reference to it (and `MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID`) in `progname.tc`. It worked. Thanks.